# Recursive aggregation return statements question

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, return, return-value

I am working on a problem that calculates all the branch sums on a given binary tree and returns the results in an array or python list, I know this is the correct answer but I am having some trouble understanding how the aggregation process happens and why if the list is being updated before subsequent function calls then why aren't the other variables.

code:

```
def branchTot(root):
    soln = []
    fin  = help(root, root.value, soln)
    return fin


def help(root, sums, soln): 
    if root.left is None and root.right is None:
        soln.append(sums)


else:
    if root.right is not None and root.left is not None :
        help(root.left, sums + root.left.value, soln)
        help(root.right, sums + root.right.value, soln)
    elif root.right is not None:
        help(root.right, sums + root.right.value, soln)
    else:
        help(root.left, sums + root.left.value, soln)

return soln
```

for example with the tree:

```
      1
    /   \
   2     3
```

the functions on the call stack would be

(3.) help(3,4,[3]) --> returned : soln = [3,4]

(2.) help(2,3,[])  --> returned : soln = [3]

(1.) help(1,1,[])

my question is why in the last(3.) call if the 'soln' variable is updated from the previous(2.) call then why aren't also the root and sum variables updated from (2.) instead of being still from call(1.)?

like why isn't it:
(since 2.right is None)

(3.) help(None,3+None,[3]) --> returned : soln = [3,4].

(2.) help(2,3,[])  --> returned : soln = [3]

(1.) help(1,1,[])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object *referenced* by `soln` is mutable and can be (and is) mutated in-place. The other values are immutable; `sums + root.left.value` creates a new object to be passed to the next call to `help`, leaving both `sums` and `root.left.value` unchanged in the current call to `help`.

Comment: why are some objects mutable and others not mutable

Comment: Ideally, all objects would be immutable; code that can't change existing values is easier to understand, and immutable values often use slightly less memory. However, mutability provides performance benefits, so some types (namely, containers like lists, dicts, and sets) are made mutable as a compromise.

Comment: By mutable you mean can be changes/over-written? Is this only in python or the same in other languages like java, c++

Comment: Right. Most languages have both. Some (Haskell, for example) don't have any mutable types. I'm not ware of any that have *only* mutable types. (No one lets you change the value of an integer like 1, for example. Note that I'm excluding something like `Integer` in Java, which is really just a container for an immutable value.)